# recommended way to store/restore user info in an android app

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I made a Utils class where I have static properties and functions that serves my app. I also have the info of the user, such as name email etc., and 2 functions to store/restore this info, so in general it looks like this:

```
public class Utils {

    static public int userId;
    static public String name;
    static public String email;

    static public void writeData(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor pref = context.getSharedPreferences("q", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        pref.putInt("userid", userId);
        pref.putString("email", email);
        pref.putString("name", name);
        pref.commit();
    }

    static public void readData(Context context) {        
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("q", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
        userId = prefs.getInt("userid", 0);
        email = prefs.getString("email", "");
        name = prefs.getString("name", "");
    }

}
```

I don't need to explain the simplicity of the above but I was wondering if there is a more recommended/standard way to do this.

Comment: Do these details need to be accessed from all context within your app or only several (perhaps one) activity?

Comment: there are a lot of ways to store/retrieve data in android, you can see this in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).
Some Useful tutorials about [Using SharedPreferences](http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/android/android-sharedpreferences-example/) and  [Using SQLite Database](http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/android/android-sqlite-database-example/)

Comment: I have several fragments. One for the user settings that will need access to all the info while the others will mostly need access to one or two (id, name or id,email etc. I have more than just 3 properties, I wrote down 3 just as an example)

Answer (score 0):

Shared preferences are not strictly for saving "user preferences," such as what ringtone a user has chosen. If you're interested in creating user preferences for your application, see [Preference Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html), which provides an Activity framework for you to create user preferences, which will be automatically persisted (using shared preferences). Although, using SharedPreferences in your case is more than an okay way of storing simple data.

Comment: Thanks. I read that in the documentation but they refer to an actual activity of user preferences while I'm talking about data interaction between fragments.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more so I can expand my answer with examples?